# vim search and replace with regex

Tags: regex, vim

I'm having trouble getting figuring out a couple of S&Rs for some very large documents I'm editing.

1. I'd like to replace all instances of `[##dname = KOxxx]` where xxx is any three-digit number with `Variable KOxxx`

I came up with `[##dname = KO\(\d\+\)]` which correctly finds the text I'd like to replace, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the "xxx" to be preserved in the replace. Any ideas?

2. I'd like to remove the characters > and < around a string. Example: >xxx< where xxx is anywhere from 2-5 characters long.

I had been using the following regex successfully a few months ago, but now it doesn't seem to be working.

```
%s#>\(\w\{2,5}\)<#\1#g
```

Any ideas why this might be failing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\d\+` is one or more numbers, not three numbers. `\d{3}` would be three numbers. Here `\w\{2,5}` you are saying the first curly brace is literal, take off the backslash, `\w{2,5}` to say 2 to 5 word characters (make it a `.` if you want any character). I'm not sure how vim's find and replace works I'd presume your grouped value for the `xxx` would be in `$1` or `\1`.

Comment: For future reference, it's better to pose multiple questions separately.

Comment: Thanks Edward, will do!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're after :)

```
:%s/\[##dname = KO\(\d*\)\]/Variable KO\1/g
```

Comment: `\d*` is not `any three-digit number `

Comment: yes, s/he can use `\d\(3}` instead to be more robust